# QTreeWidget itemExpanded signal not being emitted when expanding

Tags: c++, qt

I construct a tree of `QTreeWidgetItem` objects and for each one I do this:

```
QObject::connect( item->treeWidget(), SIGNAL( itemExpanded( QTreeWidgetItem* ) ),
                  myHandler,          SLOT( handleExpanded( QTreeWidgetItem* ) ) );
```

So basically if any of these is expanded, handleExpanded should be called? However it's never called, I expand and collapse them, I doubleclick them, nothing triggers it.

Comment: Try it with: `QObject::connect(item->treeWidget(), SIGNAL(itemExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem *)), myHandler, SLOT(handleExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem *)));`

Comment: @vahancho thanks, that fixed it, however now it triggers several times when I expand a single item, what exactly is it doing?

It's emitted exactly 4 times no matter which one I expand.

Comment: Maybe you connect your signal slot four times?

Comment: I made a check where I add the already connected ones to a list and I check if it already exists there before adding it, yet this still happens.

Comment: You wrote that you do the `connect` for each `QTreeWidgetItem` creation. You only need to connect once.